# datagridview Column Header issue

Tags: datagridview

When I load my DGV, I assign different cells backcolor depending on my column(7). This loads perfectly. The problem is when I click on any Header to sort the column, all my backcolor goes back to "nothing." Why?
All I'm doing is clicking the header to sort the column, and i don't have any code to change the backcolor when clicking on a cell.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    daM = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Kim_Items_Result", con)
    Try
        con.Open()
        daM.Fill(dtM)
        con.Close()
        dgvMain.DataSource = dtM
        With dgvMain
            .Columns("Item").HeaderText = "Part #"
            .Columns("Item").Width = 150
            .Columns("ItemDescription").Width = 600
            .Columns("PrimaryVendorNumber").Width = 400
            .Columns("PrimaryVendorNumber").HeaderText = "Vendor"
            .ClearSelection()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Dim col, col2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    'col.Visible = False
    dgvMain.Columns.Add(col)
    dgvMain.Columns.Add(col2)

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvMain.RowCount - 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("ItemDescription").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("ItemDescription").Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        End If
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("Min").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("Min").Style.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
        End If
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("Max").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("Max").Style.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
        End If
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("PrimaryVendorNumber").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("PrimaryVendorNumber").Style.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
        End If
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("StdUM").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("StdUM").Style.BackColor = Color.PeachPuff
        End If
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("UMConversion").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("UMConversion").Style.BackColor = Color.DarkSalmon
        End If
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvMain.RowCount - 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
    Next
    dgvMain.ClearSelection()

    lblTotal.Text = dgvMain.RowCount


End Sub
```

Comment: You will have to reassign the colors again after the sort (header click). When the user clicks on the header, the sort mechanism is changing the background colors back to its default state. It may be easier to use some “cell changed” event mechanism to format a changed cell to the appropriate color when the condition is met. Otherwise, you could still loop through all the rows and set the colors when the grid is sorted or a cells value changes. Pick your poison ;-).

Comment: JohnG, you're the man! thanks so much it works perfectly I used the "Sorted" event to reassign the backcolor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excelent it worked! Thanks JohnG. 
What I created a CellEndEdit event to update cells and also the background color.

```
 Private Sub ColorCode()
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvMain.RowCount - 1

        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("ItemDescription").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("ItemDescription").Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        End If
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("Min").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("Min").Style.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
        End If
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("Max").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("Max").Style.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
        End If
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("PrimaryVendorNumber").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("PrimaryVendorNumber").Style.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
        End If
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("StdUM").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("StdUM").Style.BackColor = Color.PeachPuff
        End If
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("UMConversion").Value.ToString = Nothing Then
            dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells("UMConversion").Style.BackColor = Color.DarkSalmon
        End If

        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
        If dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString = Nothing Then dgvMain.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = 1
    Next
End Sub
 Private Sub dgvMain_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvMain.CellEndEdit

    If dgvMain.CurrentCell.Value.ToString = Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If dgvMain.CurrentCell.Value.ToString = dgvMain.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString Then
        dgvMain.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value = Nothing
    Else
        dgvMain.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value = dgvMain.CurrentCell.Value
        ColorCode()
    End If
End Sub
```